# Outlook Interop: Password protected PST file headache

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

Okay, I have no problem identifying the .PST file using the Outlook Interop assemblies in a C# app.  But as soon as I hit a password protected file, I am prompted for a password.
We are in the process of disabling the use of PSTs in our organization and one of the steps is to unload the PST files from the users' Outlook profile.
I need to have this app run silently and not prompt the user.  Any ideas?  Is there a way to create the Outlook.Application object with no UI and then just try to catch an Exception on password protected files?

```
// create the app and namespace
Application olApp = new Application();                
NameSpace olMAPI = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
// get the storeID of the default inbox
string rootStoreID = olMAPI.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).StoreID;
// loop thru each of the folders
foreach (MAPIFolder fo in olMAPI.Folders)
{
    // compare the first 75 chars of the storeid
    // to prevent removing the Inbox folder.
    string s1 = rootStoreID.Substring(1, 75);
    string s2 = fo.StoreID.Substring(1, 75);
    if (s1 != s2)
    {           
        // unload the folder
        olMAPI.RemoveStore(fo);
    }    
}
olApp.Quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can automate outlook from another app. 
There is a [Logon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219914.aspx) method on the NameSpace object so that you can logon to the profile then you can do anything that you want. But I think that it will just pop up the prompt again as it automation but ..There is a 3rd libray that may help you as well to do this as it does it via mapi instead. checkout profman.dll in the [redemption libray](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/)